# Meta's just stopped processing my OpenId in Chrome

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, google-chrome

I was logged in to post [my question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52466/retagging-questions-in-terms-of-possible-answer-technologies), but it shows me logged out, and when I click on Google in the OpenId log in page the URL updates and the page returns to where I was, but I'm still logged out and I can't see any error message.

I had just restarted Chrome and reopened tabs, so it may be in a confused state, although SO and StackApps have still got me logged in after refreshing those pages.

I have closed all Meta tabs and started a new one, but it still doesn't successfully log me in (it does now get Google's permission -- i.e. from me -- to access my details).

At some point I *will* close Chrome completely and try again, but I got to get some work done :-)

*FYI I tried logging in using a new user based upon my Google Profile to post this question, but that caused a "An error occured while processing an error report." error. So I tried logging in to Meta in IE8 and it now knows about my Google Profile OpenId, but this Chrome Meta session still seems stuffed. Tried once more to submit this report via Chrome but with the same result.*

Comment: I can confirm I can successfully log out of SO, StackApps and SEDE and log in again in that Chrome session. Meta still fails for me after @S.Mark's answer.

Comment: Still meta openid login does not work in Chrome, but is ok in firefox. I have a myopenid login.

Comment: Same on Firefox. I guess it's a server problem. Had to clear the cookie manually to log in again.

Comment: @Mark, SO, and others sites are behind nginx, and meta is directly under IIS/7, so I think may be on the different servers.

Comment: Thank god for IE! *Did I just say that?!?*

Comment: Same here, and it was _just_ after a chrome beta update, so I was naturally suspecting chrome. Happened on FF also. Clearing cookies for meta solved it.

Comment: @Ivo Flipse: tempted to flag your comment as offensive

Comment: I'm also back in using the same Chrome 'instance'. I never explicitly adjusted my cookies but they may have timed-out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We moved our identity cookie to the `.example.com` domain so we can share auth among subdomains.

Prior to this point identity cookies were being served to the `example.com` domain which meant they were inaccessible to subdomains.

There was a small bug in the way this was implemented that affected meta for a little while. If you're having problems, just clear cookies for this domain (meta.stackoverflow.com) and log in again.

Answer (score 4):

Oh, Its just happened to me 20 minutes ago too, and I saw 2 cookies called

- somuser
- user

under `meta.stackoverflow.com` domain at that time, normally there was only a cookie called `somuser`, (and I deleted both cookies), now back to normal.

And looks like cookies renamed from

- user to **usr**,
- somuser to **somusr**

and Also cookie's domain changed from

- stackoverflow.com to **.stackoverflow.com**
- meta.stackoverflow.com to **.meta.stackoverflow.com**