# Notify user when their comment is removed

Tags: feature-request, support, status-declined, comments, notifications

If my comment on a post has been removed by a moderator, do I get any notification?

I've heard before of user's comments disappearing, but theres no notification to support this, or any reason as to why it was removed.

If I'm correct and comments are removed without notification, I think it would be a good idea to include notifications. This would help people understand why, and they wouldn't be left confused when their comments disappear.

Comment: no, there isn't any notification

Comment: Comments aren't important, there is no need for notifications on deletion of them. If the comment was important enough then it should have been added into the main body of the post. If it's not something of the quality / use that needs to be included in the post itself then it's not important enough to be notified about when it gets deleted.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53539/152859

Comment: I don't think you even get notified if a *post* is deleted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are no comment removal notifications, nor will there be.

Why? Because comments are second class. We don't see them as important - if you think a comment is important enough, it should be rolled into the post it is commenting on.

Comment: What if I haven't posted a question/answer? I'm simply commenting on a post (perhaps I've downvoted and wish to give reason).

Comment: @Curt - You hope the OP has read it and move on.

Comment: perhaps consider deleting the commenting feature altogether then... no need for unimportant bloat...

Comment: @musefan - It is a useful feature for the short term of a post (how else are you going to ask for clarifications or point out inaccuracies)? But for the longer term? Not so much.

Comment: @Oded: I see your point. Just can be a bit annoying going back to a post to see your comments removed with no way of knowing why, or if they had any effect. Kind of makes me think "should I even have bothered?" I guess it's only a few seconds of my life gone, much less than that spent clicking refresh on the questions page

Comment: @musefan perhaps a better question to ask would be: "under what circumstances do moderators delete comments?" That's probably been asked before on meta.

Comment: What is the correct way to point out errors in an answer (if you don't have a better answer to offer yourself, hence no post)?  If the author disagrees (or is just obstinate) he's not going to accept having such a comment rolled into his post but it should remain somewhere.  Comments might not be right, but where *is* right?

Comment: If comments are second class, why there are notifications when post is commented? It makes no sense...

Answer (score 0):

I have a different angle to this

In [this particular](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19353477/295783) case I am wondering if it was the person answering who flagged my comments - they may have become less relevant as he edited his answer to incorporate more and more of the upvoted answer's content and fixing his mistakes again by looking at how we did it.

The reason I want to know is when I make a relevant comment that is no longer relevant, I might want to change a vote, or comment with an updated more relevant comment

And in the above question, the comments gave a history of the editing and demonstrated why other answers on the page were more eligible than the currently accepted one

I personally read the comments to see the flow/development of an answer

Comment: Comments will always be "second class", as Oded said above and that won't change. So in a scenario as the one you describe, it's the responsibility of the user flagging your comments to reply to you first something like "your comments are now not relevant". Such things can't be identified automatically.

Comment: This kind of content should be edited into the question (if posted by the OP), or reposted as [a new question](/questions/ask), not posted as an answer to this question.

Comment: This was 6 years ago...

Answer (score -2):

#### Introduction

Notifying users of deleted comments would indeed be a good thing (in certain circumstances) in order to help modify unwanted behaviour.

#### Example

The behaviour I noticed which led me to attempt to re-ask this question (thank you duplicate checker) was one in which a (relatively high rep) user often posted rude comments accusing new users of being lazy. While this was perhaps true other users had often already made similar points in far more constructive ways. I flagged these comments as "Not constructive"/"Rude" and they were subsequently marked helpful and the comments were deleted and I assumed that would be the end of it. However, I have subsequently seen more of the same sort of "You are lazy, go away" style comments from the same user.

I now realise that this is most likely because they don't realise that their comments are unacceptable because they don't realise they are being deleted and so they will continue to give an aggressive impression of Stack Overflow to new users.

#### Conclusion

Therefore it would be helpful if users where informed when comments were deleted for the following reasons:

- Rude or Offensive
- Not constructive
- Too Chatty
- Other

But not:

- Obsolete

Comment: I see your point but just reply to one of those comments and explain why it's not acceptable, pointing to the fact past comments of the same sort are deleted to back your things up. If the user ignore it and keep posting rude comments, moderator has the ability to send "official" warning then if this will be ignored too, suspend the user.

Comment: In a majority of cases, it's better to let those comments quietly disappear. Notifying users every time a comment is deleted would only serve to rekindle dead flame wars. If you notice that a user is rude repeatedly, leave a custom comment explaining that. Moderators have a tool to see a user's comment full history including deleted comments. They probably won't investigate for one rude comment that looks like something said in the heat of the moment, but they will go and look if you tell them that it's more than that.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I'll admit I had considered that. Concern over creating a flame war between myself and a user I already consider aggressive held me back however

Comment: @Richard as long as you don't retaliate, it will be just a dog barking at your feet. Let him finish then flag for a cleanup.