# Reply button for comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, comment-replies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Let’s make it easier to reply within comments!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4798/lets-make-it-easier-to-reply-within-comments)

A reply button for comments could come in handy. It could be placed just next to where the pencil is shown when a commented is edited. Could work like Twitter's reply feature works.

Instead of pre-populating with the *current* display name for the user it could use a unique auto-expansion tag as suggested [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53419/auto-expand-user-names).

Comment: greasemonkey script: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38600/script-to-add-reply-links-to-comments (but that sticks to the display name at the time of the reply)