# Have a user's previous name show up as a tooltip

Tags: feature-request, display-names

When somebody changes their name I think it would be valuable for a period of time to simply mention their previous name in a tooltip while hovering over their new username in comments and answers. This avoids confusing people while reading comments with references that may be outdated, or somebody sees a name they do not recognize.

A simple "Previously, *oldname*" would work well to reduce confusion while a user is hovering over somebody's username. It wouldn't have to be a permanent fixture, but could be active for, say, 30 days after the fact.

Answer (score 1):

Even better: Since userids seem to be stable now<sup>1</sup>, [Auto-expand user names](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53419/auto-expand-user-names) could be implemented in comments to have automated name-updating and therefore abolish this confusion once and for all.

---

<sup>1</sup> Otherwise [permalinks to questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63684/new-badges-how-to-share-a-link/63686#63686) certainly wouldn't work in a consistent badge-awarding way...

Comment: This would be tough to implement. Consider someone who's name was "foo" and it was changed to "bar". Foo might be a real word. Sure it could be done for @replies only, but it wouldn't cover all references to names.

Comment: @Sam152: True, I was only referring to @replies. But mentioning a username without an @ shouldn't (intentionally) happen often - and that would also not be covered by your feature-request when mentioned user did not participate in the discussion himself