# Should question include tags that are mentioned only in answers?

Tags: discussion, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I retag a question with a tag that is based on the answer and not the question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26913/should-i-retag-a-question-with-a-tag-that-is-based-on-the-answer-and-not-the-que)
>   [Retagging questions in terms of possible answer technologies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52466/retagging-questions-in-terms-of-possible-answer-technologies)
>   [Retagging questions with the answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35842/retagging-questions-with-the-answer)

There is a question about problem X. Most of answers mention that it can be solved with technology A and show how.

Should that question be tagged with A that isn't mentioned in question itself at all?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I retag a question with a tag that is based on the answer and not the question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26913/should-i-retag-a-question-with-a-tag-that-is-based-on-the-answer-and-not-the-que), [Retagging questions in terms of possible answer technologies](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52466/retagging-questions-in-terms-of-possible-answer-technologies/52485#52485)

Comment: if `A` is in _accepted_ answer then such tagging makes good sense generally. Otherwise, I would say deciding on this would better be left to someone with _expert_ knowledge (high rep) in _technology A_ - to someone able do judge if the question is indeed relevant for tag to apply