# Should a tag matching the correct answer to a question be allowed?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits, policy

Edit:  A **more closely-related** question and answer are here:  [Retagging questions with the answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35842/retagging-questions-with-the-answer)

...and it is 'yes', whereas the less-related suggested question and answer farther above leans toward 'no'.

---

I recently came across a question where the questioner gave list of things he or she wanted to accomplish and asked for recommendations for a library that could help accomplish them.

The accepted answer was about a particular library for which there is a tag, and I thought it would be good for the page to reflect that tag.

I made an edit request where all I did was add that tag, but my edit was rejected.

I would like to know:

- whether there is a policy against attaching these kind of tag (maybe because the questioner would not have known to add it?) even though the tag does in fact apply (or whether the people who did the rejecting were acting on their own in this case), and
- whether we should have a policy to allow and encourage that kind of tagging

(Obviously I think this kind of tag should be allowed, as it increases the organization and searchability of the site.  In this case, with the tag a person could more easily find the question-answer pair by looking up whether library x can do things y and z.  ...or by just filtering by that tag in a more wide-ranging search for information about that library.  I would add that docs on a library do not highlight potential pitfalls as well as a trip to StackOverflow does.)

Comment: I agree that it is similar (and thank you for pointing it out), but that post discusses cases with multiple right answers, and which are new and still in flux (with more right answers possibly coming in).  I am talking about a question that is older and that has one clear answer.  (Also, the other question is from 2 years ago, did not seem to have much visibility, and contained a range of opinions...and I am specifically asking for the larger issue to be revisited.)