# Do we have a canonical question about retagging based on answer?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, canonical

I'm looking for a canonical question about retagging based on an answer.

I.E. in my question [When should site-specific tags be included in site recommendation questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/394086/289691), the [comment by Nij](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/394086/when-should-site-specific-tags-be-included-in-site-recommendation-questions/394110#comment1317698_394086)

> It **never** makes sense. If you know the site already, the question isn't necessary. If you have to ask the question, the site tag is meta-tagging. It's also not a question about that site either, it's a question about the network as a whole.

However, there are many questions about retagging based on answers. Some of them are closed as a duplicate.

| Question | Created | Score | Status | Links<sup>♠︎</sup> |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [Should I retag a question with a tag that is based on the answer and not the question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/26913/) | Oct 22, 2009 | 34 | Open | 14 [*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/26913?lq=1) |
| [Should we retag questions with topics proposed in the answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59333/) | Aug 2, 2010 | 13 | Open | 8 [*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/59333/) |
| [Retagging questions with the answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/35842/) | Jan 15, 2010 | 3 | Open | 7 [*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/35842/) |
| [Retagging questions in terms of possible answer technologies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52466/) | Jun 4, 2010 | 3 | Open | 7 [*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/52466/) |

Notes

♠︎ : Links before this question was posted

---

I want to improve based on a canonical question, the following:

The Meta SE consensus is that there are several stages regarding adding tags based on answers:

| Stage | User | Recommendation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Asking a question | Question Creator | Do not add tags based on the possible solutions |
| New Answer (no votes) | Question Editor | Do not add tags based on the the new answer |
| Accepted Answer | Question Editor | Add tag based on the accepted answer only if the solution will work in the long term |
| Answer well-received (high score) | Question Editor | Unclear |

Comment: Are you trying to formulate "canonical" recommendations (about adding tags to Questions because of the way they are answered) uniformly applicable to all Stack Exchange communities?  I ask because all the example Questions date to the era of Meta SO and concern SO tags and topics.  I'd be happy to post an Answer here if I knew the scope of what you want to canonize.

Comment: @hardmath The general topic is tagging, the specific topic is retagging answered questions. One case is questions in Web Applications SE, people ask how to X using Y, i.e. how to automatically add a timestamp into a Google Sheets other than manually typing it. The options/solutions are using a keyboard shortcut,  =NOW() formula then copy and paste as value only, use Google Apps Script, using an add-on or using some sort of advanced hack. Usually the OP will include only `[google-sheets]`. Assuming that the question has on answer for each option/solution Should we add a tag that corresponds...

Comment: ... to each solution? Should we add a tag only the the solution that the OP accepted? What if the solution with the highest score is no the accepted answer? Another case, here in Meta Stack Exchange. Take the [tag:site-recommendation] questions... There is a question having [tag:ask-different] but also has [tag:iPhone] the last one should be removed, as it is for questions about  the SE app for iPhone. Should we also remove [tag:ask-different]?

Comment: My recommendation in the example you describe would be almost universally "no", don't retag. Imagine... what if you had an example with 10 possible methods for solving? How could you possibly tag them all? Tags should be based on the question only, not the answers.